# Angular 2 (TypeScript): Unable to bind to object from http.get in HTML Template

Tags: http, angular, typescript, get, angular2-template

Having a devil of a time figuring out why this is happening. I've got an A2 project set up using the CLI and I have the following component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-profile-card',
  templateUrl: 'user-profile-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['user-profile-card.component.scss']
})
export class UserProfileCardComponent implements OnInit {

  public person;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  getUserProfile(){
    this.http.get('http://somedomain.com/12345')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
            person => { this.person = person.person },
            err => console.error(err),
            () => console.log(this.person.sex)
        );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUserProfile();
  }
}
```

The console log for this.person.sex shows the correct value, but when I try to bind to it from the template:

```
<div>{{ person.sex }}</div>
```

I get the following error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'self.context.person.sex')

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because all http calls are asynchronous operations and you are trying to display `person.sex` in your template before data arrive. You can use **safe navigation operator** (`?`) to "protect" your template until data arrive:

```
<div>
    {{ person?.sex }}
</div>
```

You can also use `ngIf` directive:

```
<div *ngIf="person">
    {{ person.sex }}
</div>
```

This way, your `div` won't appear in DOM until variable `person` is populated. You can read more about safe navigation operator [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator)  and more about `ngIf` directive [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html).

Comment: Wow... Such a simple thing but a huge effect. I used your first example and all is now awesome. Thanks a lot for this!